# Ember Save changedAttributes to Store only. No AJAX

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to commit Ember Data changedAttributes to the store record without triggering the AJAX call with save(). Is there an option I can pass in to rec.save() that will set the Ember Data record to clean? A workaround if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to clear ember-data flags using .save() and not make an external request.

.[save](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Model/methods/save?anchor=save)() will

> Save the record and persist any changes to the record to an external source via the adapter.

You could override the save method in the adapter and avoid the external request there by passing an adaptorOptions object to the save method.

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   updateRecord: function(store, type, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.adapterOptions.no_persist) {
           // Return a promise here containing snapshot.record
       } else {
           this.super(...arguments)
       }
    }
});

....

record.save({adapterOptions: {no_persist:true}});
```